# Disable the url in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the URL so that no one can edit the data by changing the URL

I am posting the data in URL through `get` method in php.

How can I disable the URL?

Comment: "disable the URL" instantly reveals how familiar web technologies you are with.

Answer (score 5):

You can't "disable the URL", you've stumbled upon one of the most fundamental issues of web programming: **don't trust the client!**

That is why web programmers *have* to check data to ensure it meets certain criteria before moving on...

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['example']) || ($_GET['example']!='foo' || $_GET['example']!='bar'))
{
 //error
}
else
{
 //proceed
}
?>
```